# Why my function is running before window resizes?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the header to change it's colour when the window is re-sized. But the changeColor() runs immediately after I load the site. Can anyone explain, why my changeColor() function is running before window re-sizes?

```html
<body>
  <h1>JavaScript</h1>
  <script>
    var heading = document.querySelector("h1");

    function changeColor(colour) {
      heading.style.color = colour;
    }
    window.onresize = changeColor("red");
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing "changeColor" function in your way.

Try this:

```
<body>
  <h1>JavaScript</h1>
  <script>
    var heading = document.querySelector("h1");

    function changeColor(colour) {
      heading.style.color = colour;
    }

    window.onresize = function() {
        changeColor("red")
    };
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the result of a call to `changeColor` to `window.onresize`, not the function `changeColor` itself. Your code is equivalent to:

```
var temp = changeColor("red"); // undefined, because changeColor doesn't return anything
window.onresize = temp;
```

What you can do is create a function that returns a function which uses the desired color:

```
function createColorChangeCallback(color) {
  return function() {
    heading.style.color = color; // color variable captured from enclosing function
  };
}
window.onresize = createColorChangeFunction("red");
```

Or you can use `.bind` or a lambda:

```
window.onresize = function() {
  changeColor("red");
};
```

Which are both equivalent to:

```
window.onresize = function() {
  heading.style.color = "red";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the function.

use this:

```
window.onresize = changeColor.bind(this,"red");
```

Right now, the execution of your program is:

> changeColor(red) --> assign its return value to window.onresize

Comment: I personally think that wrapping it in an anonymous function is more readable and can avoid some subtle bugs.

Answer (score 0):

you should try something like this and that should do the trick

```
<body onresize="changeColor('red');">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        heading.style.color = "red";
    });
});
```

Try this....

Comment: didn't get your point....its just the script ........i have not declared the variables.

Comment: I think you meant `"red"` instead of `red`